# Removing styling from last TR

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a `table` where I have set the `tr` style to:

`border-bottom:1px silver solid;`

The `table` is database generated, and I don't want the last `tr` to have the bottom border.

How to I stop the last `tr` from getting the styling?

Comment: I thought one cannot even style `tr`s because they are only "logical" elements.

Comment: Oh!  It was working for me in Chrome, but forgot to check it in IE, and in IE8 the styling is not working...

Comment: FWIW, it works in FF5. Interesting how things change...

Comment: Unfortunately, I need it to work in IE7 and IE8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can select the last `tr` using javascript or CSS, but if you choose to do it with CSS it won't work on all browsers (nor will the JS solution on browsers that don't have JS enabled).

jQuery:

```
$('#tableID tr:last').css('border-bottom',0);
```

or if multiple instances:

```
$('.tableClass tr:last-child').css('border-bottom',0);
```

The CSS solution would be to just use:

```
tr:last-child{
border-bottom:0;
}
```

Note that the `:last` selector selects only one instance, and as it isn't part of the CSS specification, it isn't quite as fast as `last-child` selector, but that selection may not be what you are looking for if you have nested tables etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use css2:

```
table tr:last-child {border: 0;}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('table tr:last').css('border-bottom', 'none');
```

here's a fiddle you can see it in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/AYzaN/

Answer (score 1):

Use a CSS selector for this:

```
table#mytable tr:last-of-type{
  border-bottom:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In CSS3 you can use the [not()](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-not) selector, but a better cross-browser solution (for the moment) would probably be jQuery:

```
$('table tr:not(:last-child)').css("border-bottom", "1px silver solid");
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/73LLa/)**